# Change URL with rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I change my URL from domain.com/sprekers/?spreker=value to domain.com/value with a rewrite rule with wordpress.

I've tried to change it like this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^spreker=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^sprekers/$ %1/? [R=301,L]
```

than I tested it with the htaccess tester http://htaccess.madewithlove.be If I test it on the tester everything works fine but when I do this on my wordpress site it doesn't work. This is my complete htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^spreker=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^sprekers/$ %1/? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I think it doesn't work because the /sprekers is already "made" by wordpress how can I fix this?

Cheers 
Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need to put your first code after the `RewriteBase /` rule.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^spreker=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^sprekers/$ %1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: +1, Yes that is right, order does matter and esp. for WP it is doubly important.